# My newly published Android app is not searchable on market, however it is searchable on appBrain.

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, google-play, searchable

I have published a new app to the android market called Charlotte Scooter Shop.  It has been almost 48 hours and the only way I can access the app is through a direct link:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.v1_4.B2EE5EC846A7AFF58EDFC1F0.com

or by searching on appBrain.

I cannot search for the app on the regular android market, but the direct link works???

I have checked my manifest file and cannot find any issues with that.  I did not check copy protection when publishing.

If the app is published to the android market and searchable on appBrain then that means I signed it correctly, right?

Just wondering how concerned I should be.  I have searched many many forums, and it seems most people do not have to wait over an hour or so to search for their app.  I am attaching my manifest code.
      
      
      android:versionCode="4"
      android:versionName="1.4"
      >

```
<!-- permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<application android:name="AppDelegate"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:debuggable="false"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    <!-- starting activity -->
    <activity android:name=".Act_Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <!-- screen activities -->
    <activity android:name=".Screen_About" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_CustomHTML" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_CustomText" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_CustomURL" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_QuizMultipleChoice" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_QuizScores" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_RSSReader" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_ShareFacebook" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_ShareTwitter" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_SubMenu" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_Video" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensor"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen_SingleImage" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensor"></activity>



        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".Screen_LocationMap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensor">

        </activity>



</application>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you check what you've set in the app details page on the market. What description have you given it? What about the screenshots? What countries and languages have you released it for? What are the min and max versions you support? Has the market decided that some devices can't support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android market always takes a while to update it's search rankings (as does AppBrain).
I also believe both use the popularity of an app in the search rankings. Therefore you should first have some external means to give your app a bit of popularity before it will be considered a good app to place high on search results lists.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem with one of our apps, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.chronicle.promo&hl=en , and asked Google Support about the ranking, and this is what we go as response.

Thank you for your note. When searching in Google Play, application search works across title, publisher and app descriptions. It's not easy to refine the search results appropriately when it comes to generic words like "Diary" that may also happen to be brand names or titles.

Because your app's title is made up of common words, your app won't rank high enough the search term "Diary" to be visible in search results with our current algorithms. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.

You can, however, find your app as the 12th result when searching by it's exact title. As well, a search for "Diary MobileAppMart" returns both of your diary apps as the only result.

Please note, Google Play search factors in the overall experience of your app based on user behavior and feedback. While the details of these weights and values are a proprietary part of the Google search algorithm, you can work to improve your app’s visibility by:

- Building a lasting and meaningful experience for your users
- Maintaining and improving your app through regular updates
- Encouraging users to provide feedback in the form of ratings and comments
- Providing great customer service by responding to your users and addressing issues

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. I just uploaded my new game. The only method to find it on the market is search the exact name of the app with the quotation mark and use the url of the app detail page https://market.android.com/details?id=com.shuningzhou.collectthestars
The app is in the android market, but It is just too hard to find it in the lists.